# Ordering Table A based on Rank of Table B in R

Tags: r, finance, xts

pretty newb question here, but I have not been able to track down a solution for some time:

I have an XTS object of trading indicators (*indicate*) for stock data that looks like

```
               A           XOM          MSFT
2000-11-30   -0.59        0.22          0.10
2000-12-29    0.55       -0.23          0.05
2001-01-30   -0.52        0.09         -0.10
```

And a table with an identical index for the corresponding period returns (*return*) that looks like

```
               A           XOM          MSFT
2000-11-30   -0.15        0.10          0.03
2000-12-29    0.03       -0.05          0.02
2001-01-30   -0.04        0.02         -0.05
```

I have sorted the indicator table and had it return the column name with the following code:

```
indicate.label <- colnames(indicate)
indicate.rank <- t(apply(indicate, 1, function(x) indicate.label[order(-x)]))    
indicate.rank <- xts(indicate.rank, order.by = index(returns))
```

Which gives the table (*indicate.rank*) of the symbol names ranked by their trading indicator:

```
               1            2            3
2000-11-30    XOM         MSFT           A
2000-12-29     A          MSFT          XOM
2001-01-30    XOM          A            MSFT
```

I would like to also have a table that gives the period returns based on the indicator rank:

```
2000-11-30    0.10         0.03         -0.15
2000-12-29    0.03         0.02         -0.05
2001-01-30    0.02        -0.04         -0.05
```

I cannot figure out how to call the correct symbol for all rows or just sort the table *return* based on the order of *indicate*.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Trevor J

Comment: To facilitate testing it would be better if you offered the output of dput on the first two xts objects.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I am working with about 2500 symbols here, so I gave an abbreviated representation of what the data looked like.  I would be happy to post the output but its about 7.5MB.  Is there a way to attach a file to the post?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not particularly satisfied with this solution, but it works.

```
row.rank <- t(apply(indicate, 1, order, decreasing=TRUE))
indicate.rank <- return.rank <- indicate  # pre-allocate
for(i in 1:NROW(indicate.rank)) {
  indicate.rank[i,] <- colnames(indicate)[row.rank[i,]]
  return.rank[i,] <- return[i,row.rank[i,]]
}
```

It would probably be easier to handle this if the returns and the indicators for each symbol were in the same object, but I don't know how that would fit with the rest of your workflow.

Comment: Josh, 

Thanks for your help.    I agree that more elegant solution might be had if the data was grouped better.  I attempted to do that at first, but couldn't find a way without a cumbersome loop.  But I am new at R, so I'll have another look.